# Trying to make an image move using animate

Tags: jquery, arrays, html

Im tying to make this image move from one side to another, but for some reason is not working, any ideas why?

If I change this line of code

```
var div = document.getElementById("animation");
```

To

```
var div = $("div");
```

work but it move all divs

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function(){
    var div = document.getElementById("animation");
    div.animate({top: "+=100px", left:"+=800px"}, 3000);
    div.animate({top: "+=100px", left:"-=800px"}, 3000);
    });
  });
</script>

<Button>Animate</Button>
<div id="animation" style="height:100px; width:200px; position:absolute;"><img src="images/poporkii.gif" width="281" height="186" /></div>
```

Comment: Just change `var div = document.getElementById("animation");` to `var div = $("#animation");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `var div = $("#animation");` instead of `var div = $("div");`.

**Explanation**
`var div = $("div");` targets all the `div` elements whereas `var div = $("#animation");` targets *only* the `div` with the `id` `animation`